# How to create a bucket of timestamps with a gap of X minutes in R from given timestamp values (example given)?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have a mydf table , and it has time_stamps column with devices . I want to keep merging time_stamps as long as difference between 2 consecutive time_stamps is equal or less than 30 minutes . Starting time_stamp would be marked as start_timestamp and when gap is more than 30 minutes , then I would end that visit and classify that end as end_timestamps as given in the example given below

```
df<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",4),device=rep("x",4),time_stamps=c("2020-05-13 07:50:06","2020-05-13 07:55:06","2020-05-13 08:05:06","2020-05-13 08:50:06"))
df1<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",3),device=rep("y",3),time_stamps=c("2020-05-14 07:50:06","2020-05-14 08:15:06","2020-05-14 08:25:06"))
df2<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",1),device=rep("z",1),time_stamps=c("2020-05-16 09:50:06"))
df3<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",2),device=rep("a",2),time_stamps=c("2020-05-16 09:50:06","2020-05-16 19:50:06"))
df4<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",2),device=rep("b",2),time_stamps=c("2020-05-17 09:50:06","2020-05-17 10:15:06"))
df5<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",4),device=rep("c",4),time_stamps=c("2020-05-13 07:50:06","2020-05-13 07:55:06","2020-05-13 08:05:06","2020-05-13 08:32:06"))

mydf<-rbind(df,df1,df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

This is my expected data frame

```
expected_df<-data.frame(customer=rep("XYZ",8),device=c("x","x","y","z","a","a","b","c"),
        start_timestamp=c("2020-05-13 07:50:06","2020-05-13 08:50:06","2020-05-14 07:50:06","2020-05-16 09:50:06","2020-05-16 09:50:06","2020-05-16 19:50:06","2020-05-17 09:50:06","2020-05-13 07:50:06"),
        end_startstamp=c("2020-05-13 08:05:06","2020-05-13 08:50:06","2020-05-14 08:25:06","2020-05-16 09:50:06","2020-05-16 09:50:06","2020-05-16 19:50:06","2020-05-17 10:15:06","2020-05-13 08:32:06"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is to create groups we can `group_by`. To do so we identify those records that are within `30 * 60` seconds of each other, and then use `rle` to consolidate them:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% 
  group_by(customer, device) %>% 
  mutate(time_stamps = as.POSIXct(time_stamps),
         diff = time_stamps - lag(time_stamps, default = first(time_stamps)),
         same_group_as_lag = diff <= 30*60,
         group = with(rle(same_group_as_lag), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 6
#> # Groups:   customer, device [6]
#>    customer device time_stamps         diff       same_group_as_lag  group
#>    <fct>    <fct>  <dttm>              <drtn>     <lgl>              <int>
#>  1 XYZ      x      2020-05-13 07:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#>  2 XYZ      x      2020-05-13 07:55:06   300 secs TRUE                   1
#>  3 XYZ      x      2020-05-13 08:05:06   600 secs TRUE                   1
#>  4 XYZ      x      2020-05-13 08:50:06  2700 secs FALSE                  2
#>  5 XYZ      y      2020-05-14 07:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#>  6 XYZ      y      2020-05-14 08:15:06  1500 secs TRUE                   1
#>  7 XYZ      y      2020-05-14 08:25:06   600 secs TRUE                   1
#>  8 XYZ      z      2020-05-16 09:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#>  9 XYZ      a      2020-05-16 09:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#> 10 XYZ      a      2020-05-16 19:50:06 36000 secs FALSE                  2
#> 11 XYZ      b      2020-05-17 09:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#> 12 XYZ      b      2020-05-17 10:15:06  1500 secs TRUE                   1
#> 13 XYZ      c      2020-05-13 07:50:06     0 secs TRUE                   1
#> 14 XYZ      c      2020-05-13 07:55:06   300 secs TRUE                   1
#> 15 XYZ      c      2020-05-13 08:05:06   600 secs TRUE                   1
#> 16 XYZ      c      2020-05-13 08:32:06  1620 secs TRUE                   1
```

Then is just a matter of summarizing:

```r
mydf %>% 
  group_by(customer, device) %>% 
  mutate(time_stamps = as.POSIXct(time_stamps),
         diff = time_stamps - lag(time_stamps, default = first(time_stamps)),
         same_group_as_lag = diff <= 30*60,
         group = with(rle(same_group_as_lag), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>% 
  group_by(group, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(start_timestamp = min(time_stamps),
            end_startstamp = max(time_stamps))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   customer, device [6]
#>   customer device group start_timestamp     end_startstamp     
#>   <fct>    <fct>  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 XYZ      x          1 2020-05-13 07:50:06 2020-05-13 08:05:06
#> 2 XYZ      x          2 2020-05-13 08:50:06 2020-05-13 08:50:06
#> 3 XYZ      y          1 2020-05-14 07:50:06 2020-05-14 08:25:06
#> 4 XYZ      z          1 2020-05-16 09:50:06 2020-05-16 09:50:06
#> 5 XYZ      a          1 2020-05-16 09:50:06 2020-05-16 09:50:06
#> 6 XYZ      a          2 2020-05-16 19:50:06 2020-05-16 19:50:06
#> 7 XYZ      b          1 2020-05-17 09:50:06 2020-05-17 10:15:06
#> 8 XYZ      c          1 2020-05-13 07:50:06 2020-05-13 08:32:06
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>